# powershell replace $_ if criteria meets

Tags: powershell, replace, foreach

I read a xml file and want to replace three strings.

My Code:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $files){
 (Get-Content $file) | Foreach-Object {
  $_ -replace 'TABLE_NAME="\$ZoneProdukt\$', ('TABLE_NAME="' + $ZONPRODLANG)`
    -replace 'OPTION="Copy" ', '' `
    -replace ('<JOB ','<JOB TIMETO="TEST" ') | ? {$_ -notlike "*TIMETO=`""}
 } |  Set-Content ($destination_folder + $file.name)
}
```

the last replace provides only the half of the result I
 expect.

If there are lines containing "JOB" and "TIMETO" they will not be displayed (because of Where-Object)

How to keep lines if the mentioned "TIMETO"-Attribute already exists?

examples:

> source line in file (without "TIMETO"):

```
<JOB JOBISN="30" USER="testuser">
```

> correct replace:

```
<JOB TIMETO="TEST" JOB JOBISN="30" USER="testuser">
```

....

....

> source line in file (with "TIMETO"):

```
<JOB JOBISN="30" USER="testuser" TIMETO="0400">
```

> replace -> this line will not be displayed !!

..

thanks in advance! br danijel

Comment: [Do not parse XML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1630171).

Comment: Wrap your entire `-replace` logic with parenthesis.  Or better yet, use the `.Replace()` string method, since you're not doing anything special with regex.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I will never not upvote a link to that post.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers - why not ? because of performance impact?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible
my posted code is only a part of entire replace - there are more replaces which include regex

Comment: Use regex where it's needed, otherwise you're using a hammer on a screw.

Comment: *Why not? because of performance impact?* That's explained in [this answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758162/1630171). And because PowerShell already comes with a ready-made XML parser that will do all the hard work for you. Regular expressions are just the wrong tool for dealing with XML, unless you have a *very* simple, clear-cut problem with *very* well-defined input.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an if-statement in your `ForEach-Object`:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $files){
 (Get-Content $file) | Foreach-Object {
    if($_ -like "*TIMETO=`""){
      $_ -replace 'TABLE_NAME="\$ZoneProdukt\$', ('TABLE_NAME="' + $ZONPRODLANG)`
        -replace 'OPTION="Copy" ', '' `
    }else{
      $_ -replace 'TABLE_NAME="\$ZoneProdukt\$', ('TABLE_NAME="' + $ZONPRODLANG)`
        -replace 'OPTION="Copy" ', '' `
        -replace ('<JOB ','<JOB TIMETO="TEST" ')
    }
 } |  Set-Content ($destination_folder + $file.name)
}
```

Manipulating xml using regex is generally bad practice. You should use `Get-Content` and cast as `[xml]`, which will allow you to manipulate the object. [Check out this this MSDN demo](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sonam_rastogi_blogs/2014/05/14/update-xml-file-using-powershell/).

Comment: the problem of that solution is that the other replaces(e.g. table_name and option) must be done regardless of whether "timeto" is matched in line.

Comment: @DanijeldeVasco Quick and dirty solution in edit. Seriously though, consider the object approach.